# Highlight text, like iBooks app for annotations (hopefully using TextKit)

Tags: ios, ios7, ibooks, textkit

I'm trying to build an iOS app, where from a piece text, the user can select and highlight words or phrases. Very similarly to iBooks app.

I've been reading, and I've seen answers which say that iBooks uses Javascript to render highlight text.

I'm wondering, since iOS 7 has Textkit, this changed and now there are better ways to achieve this using this framework and its classes (NSTextStorage, NSLayoutManager, etc.).

Thanks.

Comment: If you have found the solution to this problem, please post. I'm stuck with this for few days now. Please.

Comment: This question was made a long time ago. iOS has evolved a lot, and I bet there are better interfaces.

Comment: Yes, I could use subclass of NSLayoutManager and override some funcs. But I don't know the business logic.